# How combine 2 web apps under one domain

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module

I have 2 ASP.NET core projects, first one lets call it **Test** which contains angular SPA, and the second one **Test.API** which exposes a RESTfull API to the angular app, now i'm deploying 2 apps to Azure web apps under custom domain.

Test is: **www.mydomain.com**

Test.API is **api.mydomain.com**

My problems is that any call from my angular app causing an additional OPTIONS request (delay) that i want to eliminate, by rewriting request (Not redirect) that points to api.mydomain.com/* to www.mydomain.com/api/*.
And also keeping 2 different web apps.

Tried to use asp.net - **IIS URL Rewrite module** but without any luck, can someone provide me with working example or suggest other way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use Azure Web App Virtual Directory. Refer to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/) to know how to deploy multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website. Please try to deploy Test web app to the root project, and deploy Test.API to the virtual directory. After this, we can use www.mydomain.com to access the root web app, use www.mydomain.com/api to access the web app existed in virtual directory.